# Making Dictionary with common words from paragraphs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[Link to problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmxJR.png)

Please help. I am very confused on how to execute this:

This is what I currently have:

```py
def similarityAnalysis(paragraph1, paragraph2):
    dict = {}
    for word in lst:
        if word in dict:
            dict[word] = dict[word] + 1
        else:
            dict[word] = 1
    for key, vale in dict.items():
        print(key, val)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. You should always show the error message your current code gives you.  Also, try to share a fully-executable code sample with initial values for all variables.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing your code as follows:

1. You use the variable name `dict` which is a [reserved keyword](https://realpython.com/python-keywords/) (for creating dictionaries). By using this as a variable name, you will loose the ability to use the `dict` function.
2. The function uses a variable named `lst` which is not one of its arguments. Where do the values for this variable come from?
3. In the second for loop, you use the variable name `vale` but then later reference a different variable called `val`.

Otherwise, looks good.  There may be other issues, that's as far as I got.

Recommend googling the following and seeing what code you find

- "Python count the number of words in a paragraph"

***Update:***
There are many ways to do this, but here's one answer:

```py
def word_counts(lst):
    counts = {}
    for word in lst:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
    return counts

def similarityAnalysis(paragraph1, paragraph2):
    lst1 = paragraph1.split()
    lst2 = paragraph2.split()
    counts1 = word_counts(lst1)
    counts2 = word_counts(lst2)
    common_words = set(lst1).intersection(lst2)
    return {word: (counts1[word], counts2[word]) for word in common_words}

paragraph1 = 'one three two one two four'
paragraph2 = 'one two one three three one'

print(similarityAnalysis(paragraph1, paragraph2))
```

Output:

```
{'three': (1, 2), 'one': (2, 3), 'two': (2, 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

see below.

- For find common words we use set intersection
- For counting we use a dict

### Code

```
lst1 = ['jack','Jim','apple']
lst2 = ['chair','jack','ball','steve']
common = set.intersection(set(lst1),set(lst2))
print('commom words below:')
print(common)
print()

print('counter below:')
counter = dict()
for word in lst1:
  if word not in counter:
    counter[word] = [0,0]
  counter[word][0] += 1
for word in lst2:
  if word not in counter:
    counter[word] = [0,0]
  counter[word][1] += 1
print(counter)
```

output

```
commom words below:
{'jack'}

counter below:
{'jack': [1, 1], 'Jim': [1, 0], 'apple': [1, 0], 'chair': [0, 1], 'ball': [0, 1], 'steve': [0, 1]}
```

Comment: You've probably meant `set(lst1).intersection(lst2)`

Comment: Check the code and see if it works.